# Selecting wrong range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to quickly calculate a long lists unique values given several filters.

Rwave2 generates a range that starts past the end of Rwave, somehow taking values from the original "Export" range.

The first value of s = 44928 and e = 85991 and second value s = 1 and e = 2388. However the second range starts at 89855 of the original "Export" cell Range and 2388 values after. Not 1-2388 of the Rwave range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B4")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
           Dim wave As String
           wave = CStr(Range("B4").Value)
           Dim Rwave As Range
           Dim s, e As Long
           'Separate by Wave
           s = Search_Start(Sheets("Export").Range("A:A"), "A", wave)
           e = Search_End(Sheets("Export").Range("A:A"), "A", wave, s)
           Set Rwave = Sheets("Export").Range(Sheets("Export").Cells(s, "A"), Sheets("Export").Cells(e, "G"))
           Sheets("TestSheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
           Rwave.Copy Sheets("TestSheet1").Range("A1")

           For i = 6 To 56
            'Separate by Zone
            Dim Rwave2 As Range
            s = Search_Start(Rwave, "B", CStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B")))
            e = Search_End(Rwave, "B", CStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B")), s)
            Set Rwave2 = Rwave.Range(Rwave.Cells(s, "A"), Rwave.Cells(e, "G"))
            Sheets("TestSheet2").UsedRange.ClearContents
            Rwave2.Copy Sheets("TestSheet2").Range("A1")

            'Create an array of only the unique locations
            Dim tmp, cell As String
            Dim arr() As String
            tmp = "|"
            For j = 1 To Rwave2.Rows.Count
                'Only count the locations on the right level
                If Rwave2.Cells(j, "C") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C") Then
                    cell = Rwave2.Cells(j, "D")
                    If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
                        tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
            arr = Split(tmp, "|")

            Cells(i, "M") = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)
           Next i
    End If
End Sub

Function Search_Start(r As Range, c As String, y As String) As Double
    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        If InStr(r.Cells(i, c), y) <> 0 Then
                Search_Start = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Search_Start = 1
End Function

Function Search_End(r As Range, c As String, y As String, s As Variant) As Double
    For i = s To r.Rows.Count
        If InStr(r.Cells(i, c), y) = 0 Then
            Search_End = i - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Search_End = r.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Comment: If it is returning the wrongs values you're showing the wrong code. What does `Search_Start` and `Search_End` contain?

Comment: Should `s` be declared as a double?  Currently it's a `Variant`.

Comment: Why are you using a `Double` as a range index?

Comment: Integer was causing overflows, so I used Double. Long would work too, but it generates the same Error.

Comment: Double will cause an error if it's a decimal. You should use `Long` using `Double` doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Why not use `Find` instead of looping through your ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I see what's going on now.

The code below will search column `C` of the range `B5:D10`.
Because the searched range starts on column `B` - then column `C` is the *third* column, which is column `D` when looking at the whole worksheet.

Similarly you're counting rows within your range.  If worksheet cell `D7` contains the word `Yellow` then it will return `i=3` as that's the third row in your range.

```
Sub Test()

    Debug.Print Search_Start(Sheet3.Range("B5:D10"), "C", "Yellow")

End Sub

Function Search_Start(r As Range, c As String, y As String) As Double
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print r.Cells(i, c).Address
        If InStr(r.Cells(i, c), y) <> 0 Then
                Search_Start = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Search_Start = 1
End Function
```

To return the correct number use `Search_Start = r.Cells(i, c).Row`.

Comment: `Search_Start = r.Cells(i, c).Row` worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: `FIND` would probably be the better way to go though. :)

Comment: Not sure how you'd get random numbers, but never mind.  Least you got it working.  Feel free to tick the answer as accepted - should be a greyed out tick next to the up/down voting button somewhere.